# Shortening this function

Tags: php, regex, url

I wrote this code to prepare a title for a link, but I think it is a bit bulky and am wondering if anyone with a better understanding of regex would be able to reduce the following function (by merging the relevant preg_replaces). I need it to strip all current hyphens, strip multiple spaces, ensure that it is solely alphanumeric apart from the space-replacing hyphen, replace all spaces with a single hyphen and ensure that the string doesn't start with a hyphen:

```
function prepareURLTitle($title)
{

return preg_replace("/\A-/", "", str_replace(" ", "-", preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9\s]/", "", preg_replace('/\s\s+/', ' ', preg_replace('/\s?-/', '', $title)))));

}
```

An example of input and it's output:

Input:

> BRAND NEW   -  Gloves, 2 pack  //Multiple spaces are in here but the blockquote won't allow me to display them

Output:

> BRAND-NEW-Gloves-2-pack

Answer (score 3):

```
trim(preg_replace('`[^a-z0-9]+`i','-',str_replace("'",'',$title)),'-')
```

I also replaced quotes with nothing, so strings like "The cat's meow" don't become "The-cat-s-meow".

Answer (score 2):

```
function prepareURLTitle($title)
{
   return preg_replace("[^A-Za-z0-9]+", "-", $title);
}
```

This should work. You need to replace **multiple** non-alphanumeric characters with a single "-".

Answer (score 1):

```
preg_replace('~[^a-z\d]+~i','-',preg_replace('~^[^a-z\d]+(.*?)[^a-z\d]+$~i','$1',$title));
// or
preg_replace(array('~^[^a-z\d]+(.*?)[^a-z\d]+$~i','~[^a-z\d]+~i'),array('$1','-'),$title);
```

With an example…

```
$title = '  BRAND   NEW -   Gloves, 2 pack -  ';
echo preg_replace(array('~^[^a-z\d]+(.*?)[^a-z\d]+$~i','~[^a-z\d]+~i'),array('$1','-'),$title);
```

will return

> BRAND-NEW-Gloves-2-pack

Answer (score -1):

```
function prepareURLTitle($title)
{
   return preg_replace( "/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/", "-",str_replace("-", "",  $title));
}
```

DEMO: http://codepad.org/lPSQQBys

OUTPUT:

> BRAND-NEW--Gloves--2-pack

Comment: This would result in `BRAND NEW - Gloves, 2 pack` becoming `BRAND-NEW---Gloves--2-pack`

Comment: @kevlar1818 I fixed it (sort of).

Comment: That only replaces all non-alphanumeric characters with hyphens. Particularly examples like "foo: bar" would become "foo--bar", while that should become "foo-bar".